# determine row index in dynamic created data Table aspx.net

Tags: asp.net

I have dynamically created data Table bind to Grid View.Each row is adding on button click event.Now in button click event i need to determine position of row in data Table, and replace row values with another on that button click. In this line I'm changign row value, but how to tell him on which row should put this values   dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Artikal"] = Label12.Text; ?Below is my code. HELP!

//method for creating row

```
           private void AddNewRecordRowToGrid()
         {

        if (ViewState["Markici"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {


                    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Democookie"];
                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();

                    drCurrentRow["FirmaID"] = Request.Cookies["firma"].Value;
                    drCurrentRow["Godina"] = Request.Cookies["godina"].Value;
                    drCurrentRow["KasaID"] = Request.Cookies["kasa"].Value;
                    drCurrentRow["MarkicaID"] = 222;//Request.Cookies["kasa"].Value;
                    drCurrentRow["Datum"] = DateTime.Now;
                    drCurrentRow["Masa"] = Session["masa39"];
                    drCurrentRow["VrabotenID"] = Session["New"];
                    drCurrentRow["Artikal"] = Label3.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Cena1"] = Label4.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Kolicina"] = Label5.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Smena"] = Session["smena1"];
                    drCurrentRow["VkIznos"] = Label6.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["VkDanok"] = Label8.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["SySDatum"] = DateTime.Now;
                    drCurrentRow["Vid"] = Label23.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["EdMera"] = Label10.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["ArtikalID"] = Label9.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["TarifaID"] = Label7.Text;
                }


                //Removing initial blank row  
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
                {
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[0].Delete();
                    dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();

                }

                //Added New Record to the DataTable  
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.InsertAt(drCurrentRow, 0);
                //storing DataTable to ViewState  
                ViewState["Markici"] = dtCurrentTable;

                //binding Gridview with New Row  
                GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                GridView2.DataBind();


            }
        }
    }
```

//Button click event,here call method for creating row

```
             protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {

     DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];

        if (Label37.Text == "0")
        {
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Kolicina"] = Label5.Text;
        }


        if (Label37.Text != "0")
        {

            Counter = Counter + 1;

            dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Kolicina"] = Convert.ToInt32(Label37.Text) + Counter;

        }



//Here I'm replaceing row values, but I need to determine row index,to know on wich row I;m changing values.
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Artikal"] = Label3.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Cena1"] = Label4.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["VkIznos"] = Label6.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["VkDanok"] = Label8.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["EdMera"] = Label10.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["ArtikalID"] = Label9.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["Vid"] = Label23.Text;
        dtCurrentTable.Rows[0]["TarifaID"] = Label7.Text;

        dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();
        GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        RemoveDuplicates(dt);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Select()` to get the row you need and `Rows.IndexOf()` to find the index of the row.

```
     If (dtCurrentTable.Select("Artikal='" + Label3.Text + "'").Length > 0) {
          int rowIndex = dtCurrentTable.Rows.IndexOf(dtCurrentTable.Select("Artikal='" + Label3.Text + "'")[0]);
     }
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h71xaeh0(v=vs.110).aspx for more information on the `Select()` method.